# navigation bar line underneath the selected item

Tags: jquery, html, css, styles

I would like to get in the navigation bar line underneath the selected item for style

Similar to the example below with CSS. I have looked all day I know this is possible.

Almost like a margin but with a different color say a rectangle selected item with the bottom with a line. I tried to put an image this description but it said it required 10 reputations ????

Comment: Post the code to get quick help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want give each selected menu different colors underneath,

Add data property data-color ="red" or data-color="blue" for each li

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li data-color="red">Menu Item 1</li>
  <li data-color="blue">Menu Item 2</li>
  <li data-color="green">Menu Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Write jquery on click event

```
$(function() {
   $("#menu").find("li").on("click", function() {
                 $("#menu").find("li").css("border-bottom","none");
                 $(this).css("border-bottom","1px solid " + $(this).data("color"));
                           });
});
```

you can use hex color codes on data attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can do pretty much anything (style-wise) if that's your only goal.
Did this fairly quick. (Styles may be pretty bad but this is just to show the concept)

```
$("li").on("click", function(){
    $("li").removeClass("line");
    $(this).addClass("line");
});
```

Here, `line` being my css class.

http://jsfiddle.net/shriek/N8gEj/1/